# Ajax: Completely replace div content with new data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am building a currency switcher and integrating it in my site where users can switch between 2 currencies. its a reservation site that has a reservation form positioned on the left with the booking content taking up the rest of the page

The prices on the site are defaulted/set to one currency in the backend(USD) and the user will have the ability to choose between this and another currency.

When the user selects the other currency, the page reloads and prices are set to this currency. Now, the small issue occurs when a user changes input on the reservation form. lets say a user wants to change the checkout date, once they do this, the content on the page reloads using ajax. what is happening is: if the user has switched to the other currency and makes a change on the reservation form, the default currency(USD) loads for like a few seconds and is then replaced by the other currency. so picture this, you've switched the currency from the default and you modify your reservation form by changing one of the inputs, as the page ajax-reloads, you're presented with the default price momentarily then the correct(the currency you are using) displays

So in short, looks like the div that carries the price first loads the default currency then switches after(takes like 1-5 seconds). this is not really ideal, can't the div just load the correct currency at once?

here's the code handling this:

```
//there's a function that checks currency...
    if(currency_param == "KES")
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else 
        {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
            {
                    area.content_area.find('.gdlr-tail-currencyprice').html(this.responseText);
            }
        };
        var result = data.content.match(/\$[\d\.]+ \/ [^<]+/gi);
        var newArray = [];

        $('.gdlr-tail-currencyprice').each(function(index, el)
        {
            var num_price = parseFloat(result[index].replace( /[^\d\.]*/g, ''));
            newArray.push(num_price);
        });

        newArray.push({currency_param});
        newArray = JSON.stringify(newArray);

        xmlhttp.open("GET","switchcurrency.php?q="+newArray,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
       }
    }
```

`switchcurrency.php` simply takes the amount passed to it and converts to the required currency

the price is carried in the  `gdlr-tail-currencyprice` class and as described above, this is the problematic part. loading the default value, then a few seconds later, displaying the correct value. this part handles that:

```
area.content_area.find('.gdlr-tail-currencyprice').html(this.responseText);
```

Hope my long post has made my question clear: what could i be doing wrong or if not, is there a way to replace div content completely with the new value supplied?

Comment: What triggers the above?

Comment: hi, if you added jquery tag, why you dont use $.ajax?

Comment: Add prices of different currencies in data-attributes in the attributes on first render? Then change content of the price elements with data from its attributes matching the selected currency using `$('.currency-selector').change(function() {...});` ?

Comment: @cwallenpoole its triggered by the `slideUp' event on the reservation form i.e. once a value on the reservation form is changed this is triggered

Comment: Has been a few days since you opened this question @suo, have any of the comments/answered helped? If not, what is still the problem? What did you try in the mean time? If any of the answers solved your issue, feel free to mark an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're making it too difficult on yourself. As I mentioned in my comment on your question, you could add the different prices for the different currencies into data-attributes on the elements that display a price. If you use [standardized names for currency](http://www.xe.com/iso4217.php) attributes on elements and the same names for the values of the currency-selector, you make it a lot easier on yourself.

For example:

```
<select name="currency-selector">
    <option value="EUR">Euro</option>
    <option value="NZD">NZ Dollar</option>
    <option value="USD">US Dollar</option>
</select>
```

Further, you then also have stuff throughout your page that should display a price for something. You say reservations, so I'm assuming it's a booking page of something, lets assume a hotel.

Hotel A, Floor 1, Room 123
Price per night:
EUR 100
NZD 110
USD 120

With the data, create/render an element with whatever system you're using, such as below

```
<input type="radio" name="select-room" class="contains-price" data-price-eur="100" data-price-nzd="110" data-price-usd="120">123, first floor
```

Somewhere you'll have a table of some kind (obviously created using `<div>` elements instead of `<table>`, right? Right!? :) )

There you can then use/modify displayed prices. Get them using the [`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) function, when the selected currency gets modified.

```
$('.currency-selector').change(function() {
    var currency = $(this).val(),
        roomPrice = $('input[name="select-room"]').data('price' + currency);

    // Now display the `roomPrice` somewhere, such as the mentioned table
});
```

This is just an example, as a lot is unclear in your question. However, this does answer this part of your question:

> So in short, looks like the div that carries the price first loads the
>   default currency then switches after(takes like 1-5 seconds). this is
>   not really ideal, can't the div just load the correct currency at
>   once?

Changes made like this, using `.change()` are immediate.

---

To do this automatically for all prices in your form, you could modify the code example to something along these lines:

```
$('.currency-selector').change(function() {
    var currency = $(this).val();

    // Loop through all elements that have the class "contains-price"
    $.each('.contains-price', function(index, $element) {
        var roomPrice = $element.data('price' + currency);

        // Now display the `roomPrice` somewhere, such as the mentioned table
        // NOTE: specifically do not loop all inputs in a form using $('input') as this does not account for <textarea> and <select>
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you switch currencies, you should memorize that in cookies or something, so that server can render ajax response with a correct currency.

If it is a query param, then it's enough already. Server *knows* about current currency, why does it render default one?